# How to cc multiple emails for a google form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google apps script that will email the form submission to the user who filled out the form. I currently have the script cc to only my email and I can't seem to figure out how or if I can cc the form submission to more than one email.

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo,subject,body, {
     htmlBody: body,
     cc: 'iscaro@oakland.edu'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just separate your desired cc recipients with commas, like so:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo,subject,body, {
     htmlBody: body,
     cc: 'iscaro@oakland.edu,someother@email,etc'});
```

Comment: Concatenation would work although better used for addresses stored in variables. `cc: 'email@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com, email3@gmail.com'` would work fine for this purpose.